# Optional and non-optional args for constructor type check

Tags: typescript

I have two class `A` and `B`.

`A` has a construction arg `n: number` and `B` also have the same construction arg but optional: `n = 42`.

I want to save them to a `DICT` and use a key to select one of them by a function.

However, I got a `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature` error in TypeScript.

```
class A {
  constructor(n: number) {
    //
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(n = 42) {
    //
  }
}

const a = new A(42)
const b = new B(42)

const DICT = {
  a: A,
  b: B,
}

function test(k: keyof typeof DICT) {
  const e = new DICT[k](42)
  // ^^^ ERROR: [ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
}
```

My question is: how can I make the above code work?

`A` & `B` all can be instantiated by `new X(42)` so I believe there must be a way to do `new DICT[k](42)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the compiler doesn't automatically convert `typeof A | typeof B` into the almost-the-same type `new (n: number) => A | B`.  The former type can't be newed because [unions of function types are not considered callable](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294) (and the same likely goes for constructors). The latter type *is* newable, because it has a single `new` signature but returns a union type.

So the compiler doesn't do this conversion automatically but if you do the conversion manually it won't complain:

```
function test(k: keyof typeof DICT) {
  const ctor : new (x: number) => A | B = DICT[k];  // okay
  const e = new ctor(42);  // okay
}
```

You could do that in one line with a type assertion:

```
function test(k: keyof typeof DICT) {
  const e = new (DICT[k] as new (x: number) => A | B)(42);  // also okay
}
```

but since type assertions are less type safe than type annotations, I prefer the annotation version above.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you for the in-depth explanation and the examples!